# Determining Azure SQL Database requirements

Tags: sql-server, azure

I'm looking into moving an SQL Server database project to the cloud using Azure SQL Database. I'm just wondering what metrics I can use from SQL Server to help determine what my needs will be on Azure.

The size of the database is around 150GB, so I understand what my needs are in terms of storage, I'm just not sure what metrics I can use to translate my database usage to the DTU benchmark metrics that the various service tiers on Azure SQL use.

Answer (score 1):

Some good links from Microsoft to help translate DTU to actual metrics:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn741336.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn741336.aspx

Short version, look at a combination of concurrent user sessions, and the number of transactions over a unit of time.

Take a look at the perfmon counters:
SQL Server/SQL Statistics/Batch Requests/sec
...to get an idea of number of transactions

and

SQL Server/General Statistics/User Connections
...to get an idea of user sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Dbwatch have just created a repport where we run various benchmarks on Azure SQL databses in various datasenters around the globe.

Our tests indicate a performance difference of up to 500% between locations.

The report can be found here:
http://dbwatch.com/azure

We also provide our tool for free for a small number of database instances if you would like to compare the performance of different mashines while considering to migrate.